# populate dropdownlist from jsonresult using .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list that I need to dynamically populate based on the selection of another. It all works up to the point that I have to render the new data in the dropdown list after clearing the list first. The list clears, but then fails to populate the new data being returned from the controller. I am attempting to use .each for this.

Here's the controller method in question:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult UpdateDocumentSubType(string DocumentType)
{
    List<SelectListItem> DocumentSubTypeList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    PropertyModel model = new PropertyModel();
    int DocTypeID = 0;
    //get DocTypeID
    DocTypeID = model.GetDocTypeID(DocumentType);
    //gets new document subtype list
    DocumentSubTypeList = model.GetDocumentSubTypes(DocTypeID);
    //return document subtype list
    return Json(DocumentSubTypeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As you can see, I'm returning a serialized json result of List.

On the view, I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateDocumentSubType","Document")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { DocumentType: SelectedDocTypeText },
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        var select = $("#Docs_DocumentSubTypeID");
        select.empty();
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            select.append($('<option></option>').val(item).html(index));
        });
    }
});
```

This is where it all falls apart.  The code hits select.empty(): and executes it successfully, but then as the "text" value of the SelectListItem, it instead provides the index element of the array of objects.  Essentially, the tags render something like this:

```
<option value="[object Object]">1</option>
<option value="[object Object]">2</option>
<option value="[object Object]">3</option>
<option value="[object Object]">4</option>
```

I have verified that the data IS being passed. When I take the .each and put it in its own function, call that function, and add "debugger;" to it, I can see the data in the resulting "data" as four elements of [object, object].

As you may have guessed, JQuery isn't my strong suit, so any assistance would be appreciated. :)

Comment: what do you get in `data`. could you spend that to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should not be returning `List<SelectListItem>` in your `UpdateDocumentSubType` method - there is no point returning the extra properties of `SelectListItem` back to the client when you never use them. All you need to return is an anonymous object containing 2 properties, one for the option value, and one for its display text.

You have not shown the model,but assuming it contains properties say `int ID` and `string Name`, then it would be (say)

```
var data = db.YourTable.Where(...).Select(x => new
{
    Value = x.ID,
    Text = x.Name
};
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The reason why your seeing `value="[object Object]"` is that your returning an array of complex objects so `item` in `$.each(data, function (index, item) {` is referring to an object containing properties `Value`, `Selected`, `Text`, `Group` etc. (i.e. the properties of `SelectListItem`), so you script needs to be

```
$.each(data, function (index, item) {
    select.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).html(item.Text));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new as well so this might not be correct. 
Try

```
    $('<option></option>').val(item[index]).html(index));
```

or

```
    $('<option></option>').val(item[0]).html(index));
```

instead of what you wrote.

I need some more information. Can you share the github repo?

I am working on something very similar and this is what I did:

(Look at render function from line 85 to 96)
https://github.com/stephenhu3/codepal/blob/development/js/youtubeComponent.js

It worked for me.